# MySQL: transfer constraints to a read-only database?

Tags: mysql, constraints

I am copying individual tables from a master databases to a number of read-only slaves (the mysql user is restricted to read-only).  One easy way to copy tables is:

```
CREATE TABLE slave_db.x LIKE master_db.x;
INSERT INTO slave_db.x SELECT * FROM master_db.x;
```

This will **not** copy the foreign keys or set the auto increment index correctly.  Is there any reason to transfer the constraints, given there is no possibility of slave database modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if it is only to read purposes you don't need to copy the constraints. It will be even faster this way (Although you should create appropriate indexes).

Also, you can do as simple as:

```
CREATE TABLE slave_db.x as 
   SELECT * FROM master_db.x;
```